# Ruby rails WEBrick server exiting with errors I don't understand

Tags: ruby, webrick

I've created an app but when I start the rails server I'm getting the following output. Anyone point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong please? I'm pulling my hair out!

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:1
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:4
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `const_get'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:131:in `session_store'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:172:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:146:in `default_middleware_stack'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `build_middleware_stack'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:37
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/khussain/delete/config/environment.rb:5
    from /home/khussain/delete/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/khussain/delete/config.ru:4
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/khussain/delete/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/khussain/delete/config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above doesn't work, then it's probably because you don't have a .Gemfile ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a gem is missing (openssl), without seeing the code I'm not sure.

The best thing would be to run:

```
bundle install
```

If this still doesn't work try adding openssl to your Gemfile and running `bundle install` again